# Observable not updating value after page refresh when using router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, observable

I am using `Angular2 RC5` and `@angular/router` with a simple `router-outlet` element. I have an `Observable` that's working fine in the view but it's not working when you do a page refresh (F5 or CTRL-F5). I have this in Chrome (latest) and IE11 (and probably other browsers).
Currently I have a workaround but I don't understand why my changes aren't reflected in the view automagically.

The project is rather large so trying to minimize it here:

In MyService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    initialValue: MyObject = new MyObject(); // actually I read this from local storage...

    _information: BehaviorSubject<MyObject> = new BehaviorSubject(this.initialValue);
    get obsMyObj(): Observable<MyObject> {
        return this._information.asObservable();
    }

    myServiceFunction() {
         return this.http.get(`api/myUrl`)
            .map(this.extractMyInfo);
    }

    extractMyInfo = (res: Response): MyObject {
        let body = res.json();
        var myObject = new MyObject().mapAllProperties(body);
        this._information.next(myObject);
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

In MyComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[header]',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.header.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
    myObject: MyObject = new MyObject();

    ngOnInit() {
            this.myService.obsMyObj.subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.myObject = data;
                    });
    }
}
```

In MyView.html

```
<div>
    <img [src]="myObject?.picture"> <!-- this always works, I see the picture after page refresh -->
    <p>{{myObject?.prop1 }}</p> <!-- this does not work after page refresh -->
</div>
```

Another component does the actual service call to `myServiceFunction`, that's why I created an observable to display it in `MyComponent.ts`.

Instead of using `this.myObject = data` and assigning properties manually, it works for every page refresh...

```
this.myObject.prop1 = data.prop1;
this.myObject.prop2 = data.prop1;
```

When debugging, the subscribe method is called with the correct data for the initial state and on page refresh.

I tried binding the observable directly instead of using an object in my component.

I tried using the async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem comes from the `ngOnInit` of your `MyComponent`. Could you try to subscribe on `this.myService.obsMyObj()` instead of `this.myService.obsMyObj` ?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.obsMyObj().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.myObject = data;
    });
}
```